# C# Cast a enum InvalidCastException error

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, casting, enums

So i have this old code that uses Firebird, i took the code from there since it worked perfectly, but here it doesnt. and throws me a InvalidCastException.

So wat am i trying

```
animal.FeedScheduleType = (BcFeedScheduleType)drAnimal["feedschedule_type"];
```

So i try to pull something out my datatable and place it in animal.FeedScheduleType. Now my cast points a a public enum

```
    public enum BcFeedScheduleType
{
    Default = 0,
    FromList = 1,
    Group = 2
}
```

and animal.FeedScheduleType is

```
private BcFeedScheduleType _feedScheduleType;

public BcFeedScheduleType FeedScheduleType
    {
        get { return _feedScheduleType; }
        set { _feedScheduleType = value; }
    }
```

But whenever it hits this it throws me the InvalidCastException error and i dont know why, i searched here and google but was unable to find anything about casts like this.

Edit: the Type inside the database is a integer

Comment: What's the data type of the record in the database?

Comment: I have it palce inside the database as a integer,

Comment: Try to read the return value from the database using a temporary variable declared as _var temp_ then using the debugger check what is the value returned from your database before trying any cast.

Comment: Thanks, Tho Racil Hilan his answer made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
animal.FeedScheduleType = (BcFeedScheduleType)Convert.ToInt32(drAnimal["feedschedule_type"]);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UxSAkQ).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting to an int first?

```
animal.FeedScheduleType = (BcFeedScheduleType)(int)drAnimal["feedschedule_type"];
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it throws me the same error im afraid

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your drAnimal is returning a string and not an int. If this is the case, then

`animal.FeedScheduleType = (BcFeedScheduleType)Int.Parse(drAnimal["feedschedule_type"]);`

If you are not sure what type drAnimal is, you can do something like:

`var feedschedule_type = drAnimal["feedschedule_type"];`
`Console.WriteLine("feedschedule_type is {0}", typeof(feedschedule_type));`

Basically, you need to get it into an int and then use the standard cast as you've done in your question.

Finally, make sure the feed schedule type has a valid value. I.e., make sure its value is either 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ran into this recently when using `SqlParameter`.

My guess is that `drAnimal["feedschedule_type"]` is being stored as a `SqlDbType.Int` or `object`. In order to cast my parameter, I had to do something similar to the following:

```
(int)(SqlDbType.Int)(drAnimal["feedschedule_type"]);
```

You may have to use a similar chain to get the actual int value and coerce it into your Enum.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, the best way to convert db fields to integers is by using `Convert.ToInt32(drAnimal["feedschedule_type"])` if the field is not nullable. If it is nullable, then the best is to use `drAnimal["feedschedule_type"] as int?`.

Comment: Possibly, but `Convert` fails miserably if the type is technically a `SqlDbType.Variant`, hence the initial cast.